# ServiceStack dll are not found in release mode

Tags: servicestack

I have a problem while compiling my app in release mode. I receive the following error:

*The type or namespace name 'ServiceStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

My project is using full .NET 4.0 ( no client profile ).

When I switch back to debug mode, every thing works fine.

Could somebody help me please?

[image]

Comment: I would do a clean + rebuild all just to make sure. But the errors in that screenshot is unreadable, can you provide a link to a full-screen version?

Comment: Clean + rebuild is not working. The full size image is availiable here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/403/servicestackinrelasepro.png/

Comment: ok, fixed. problem was in missing references in release mode

Comment: Add your answer as an answer and mark it as correct :)

Comment: @DavidCrook: done, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, fixed. problem was in missing references in release mode